# XRDP gives checkerboard screen

Tags: rdp, xrdp

Just finished setting up a new server(first one, I'm super new to all of this so apologies if this is something obvious that I couldn't figure out for whatever reason) and have been trying to set up XRDP so I can log into my server remotely, but whenever I login from Remote Desktop on a Windows 7 comp, all I get is black and white checkerboard with a bold X for a cursor, nothing else appears and sometimes Remote Desktop will just close itself after a few seconds.

I'm running running Gnome for a gui on my server and have ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed

I have tried setting `.xsession` to make ubuntu run in 2d(I think the exact is `gnome-session -session=Ubuntu-2d`) which didn't solve it

I also tried this- c-nergy.be/blog/?p=5382 I wasn't able to finish this one though because whenever I tried echo `mate-session> ~/.xsession` I would get denied/permission blocked. I tried to `chmod mate-session` and `.xsession` but that didn't seem to do anything either lol..

Any help is appreciated!

On a side note: I'm kinda curious what all of this stuff means/why it does what it does, as I've said, I'm super new to Ubuntu and all this stuff and have been having trouble teaching myself >.<

Thanks!

Comment: That is the default X server behavior before any program runs.  You may need to invoke a window manager directly.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu-2d is not used anymore. Here how to do that using xfce  session.

first Install xrdp:

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

Install XFCE4 or any other supported:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

Edit our `.xsession` file in your home:

```
echo xfce4-session >~/.xsession
```

Edit  `startwm.sh` file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh
```

In the `wm_start()` Add the line `startxfce4` just directly under:

```
 if [ -r /etc/default/locale ]; then
    . /etc/default/locale
    export LANG LANGUAGE
  fi
```

so the function looks like:

```
wm_start()
{
  if [ -r /etc/default/locale ]; then
    . /etc/default/locale
    export LANG LANGUAGE
  fi

startxfce4


  # debian
  if [ -r /etc/X11/Xsession ]; then
    . /etc/X11/Xsession
    exit 0
  fi
.....

}
```

Now save and exit then restart xrdp.

```
sudo service xrdp restart
```

Now you can connect normally to your Ubuntu using xfce for remote sessions.